# Why does typescript allow number entry in an enum if one value is set to a number?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

```
 enum Type{
    Video, 
    BlogPost = "BLOG_POST", 
    Quiz = "QUIZ"
}
```

I have the following code in type script, if I have a function `createContent`

```
const createContent = (contentType:Type) => {
    console.log(contentType)
}
```

and call this function using

```
createContent(10)
```

this works. However, if all enum types are set to strings in the following code it does not allow a number to be passed in. Why is this?

```
enum Type{
    Video = "VIDEO", 
    BlogPost = "BLOG_POST", 
    Quiz = "QUIZ"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because an enum instance without a declared value is just an incrementing number. If you didn't write strings to it, it would mean something like this:

```
enum Type{
    Video = 0, 
    BlogPost = 1,
    Quiz = 2
}
```

Therefore, (if you leave one empty), your enum `Type` is not of type `string`, but rather `string | number` and therefore you are allowed to pass a number OR a string.